# UIView animateWithDuration animates only once

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiimageview

I have set an animation block to start when the user performs a search. When the search is complete a new view is pushed. This works fine until the user selects the back button and attempts the search again, now the animation does not start.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0.0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear)
                 animations:^{

                     _collectionImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

The animation is just a spinning disc before anyone asks, and the completion block is called when the pushed view loads. Any help to why it will not animate on multiple searches would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set a break point to check that the animation code is being run?  It sounds like the second time either the code just isn't being run or possibly the collectionImage object is nil.

Comment: I can visibly see that the code isn't being run. The object is connected via an IBOutlet if that is of any help.

Comment: What function is the code inside? When you say visibly see have you set a breakpoint on the start of the code i.e. at the [UIView animate bit... and did it stop there when you expected it to?  If not then I would check what is supposed to be running the function.

Comment: I have just added the UIImageView programmatically and it works correctly. Not to sure why IB messes this up.

Comment: In the property line try setting it to strong instead of weak.  and then connect it back up using IB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hi this is your problem...

your change the affine value x to y

so now your transform value is y then again your equating to y =y

then how it could work....

initially you need to store the transform value the then animate it after completing the animation you need to restore the value

in `viewDidLoad` do like this:

```
initalTransform=_collectionImage.transform;


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0.0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear)
                 animations:^{

                     _collectionImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
_collectionImage.transform=initalTransform;
                 }];
```

try this.... this is an idea you need to implement as your logic...

Comment: _collectionImage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity is all that needs to be set in the completion block, as this resets the transform.

Answer (score 0):

use `CGAffineTransformRotate(<#CGAffineTransform t#>, <#CGFloat angle#>)`
you must start rotation from curent transform